# Unhandled Promise rejection : Timeout thrown with unit test and angular 14

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular14

I have recently upgraded our project to angular 14 where the tests were running fine before(around 4k tests in the project using jasmine/Karma)

I have upgraded Karma to 6.4.1 and Karma jasmine to 5.1.0. Now I seem to be getting random test failures (one run shows error in one component while the other run shows same error in the some other random component)

The errors are of the same format for the components:

The testName

```
    Unhandled Promise rejection : Timeout thrown
```

All these tests have no promise rejections in the mocks and seem to be random
Has anyone across a similar issue?

Comment: Have you tried running a single test that fails? Is the error still there if you run a single test?

Comment: Yes running the single test that fails runs fine and for the next full test run it appears to run fine but the same ~"Unhandled Promise rejection : Timeout thrown" appears for another component test